# dompdf unable to display forloop with array in my code

Tags: forms, pdf, dompdf

I have html form, upon click on submit button, i am trying to create pdf report by using dom pdf. This is my expected output in pic expected out put in pdf everything is working fine but for loop section creating issue. can i have help from this prestigious forum to fix this issue ?? here is my code to convert post values of form into pdf with dompdf

````
              $dompdf = new Dompdf(); 
             $dompdf->loadHtml('
           <table class="center" border=0  width=450>
          <tr><td><b>Mrno : </td><td>'.$_POST['mrno'].'</td><td><b>Name : </td><td>'.$_POST['name1'].'</td></tr>
           <tr><td><b>Bill No : </td><td>'.$_POST['bilno'].'</td><td><b>Bill Date : </td><td>'.date('d-M-Y',               strtotime($_POST['bildate'])).'</td></tr>
          <tr><td><b>Phone No : </td><td>'.$_POST['mobno'].'</td><td><b>Mod of Payment : </td><td>'.$_POST['modpyment'].'</td>                   </tr>
          </table>
               <br>
            <table class="center" border=1  width=600>
              
              for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['servproname']);$i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>".$_POST['servproname'][$i]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$_POST['discunt'][$i]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$_POST['price1'][$i]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$_POST['qty'][$i]."</td>";
             echo "<td>".$_POST['tot4'][$i]."</td>";
                } 
                   
                 </table>
                     ');
                  $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
                      $dompdf->render();
                  $dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
               exit(0);
                      }
                     ?> ```
````